# Unable to connect two telscale ss7 instances initiated on two different centos machines

Tags: networking, gsm, restcomm, ss7

I am trying two connect two machines using ss7 protocol. I am very much new in the field and has almost very little knowledge.
I have restComm-jss7-7.1.1.1385 telscale simulator.
I want to initiate testerHost on one machine and access it from a different machine on same LAN. What I'm trying to do is that I'm trying to run ATI client on one machine and ATI Server on the other how can I do so. Would be thankful for any help. I'm using CentOS 7 on both PCs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I was facing was actually the firewalld of CentOS 7 and SELinux as well were creating issues. I disabled them because they were blocking the ports and as soon as I disabled firewalld and SELinux, the M3UA layer got connected and thus both the instances were working fine.